# Referencing App Object Across Multiple Build Targets iOS

Tags: ios, swift, targets

I need to make several versions of an iOS application each with a different target and name. Most of the differences between the applications are in the applications resources and not the source code. I am trying to share as much source code across versions as possible.

My issue arises when I try to access the application object in a version which does not have the same name as the original. For instance, I have two versions of the application named *UserApp* and *UserApp2* and the following code which references the data store:

```
var user = UserApp.User
```

When I try to run this code in the *UserApp2* target, it throws an error saying *UserApp* is undefined.

My question is: How can I make this code load the proper application object depending on what target is currently running? I would like a solution that can be used across all targets without the need to change code.

EDIT: The UserApp object is an XCDataModel.

Answer (score 0):

The UserApp class might not be added in all of your application targets. verify the target membership for the class.

[image]

Comment: The UserApp object has membership across all targets. Also, I neglected to mention that UserApp is a data model and not a class.

Comment: Is this coredata .xcdatamodel file?

Comment: Yes it is UserApp.xcdatamodel file.

Comment: I wonder if you can use .xcdatamodelId file in you code like this for any of the targets.